# removing spaces after <para> nodes in xslt

Tags: xslt

i've the below xml in which after the transformation the white space needs to be removed.

```
<section level="sect1" number-type="manual" num="I.">
    <title>INTRODUCTION</title>
    <para>
        <phrase>14.001</phrase> When a company in financial difficulty is unable to discharge its debts when they are due, a creditor has the right to take actions to, for example, realise assets or to have the company wound up compulsorily. However, putting the company in liquidation at the first sign of financial difficulty may not be the optimal choice for every stakeholder in the firm. Employees will lose their jobs. The company will lose its productive capacity, especially if the business is to be sold piecemeal. Unsecured creditors may not be able to recoup a penny from their investment. On the other hand, if the company is given a respite or, better still, some assistance in other forms, such as injection of fresh capital, in addition to some breathing space, the company may be nurtured back to its financial health. Even where resuscitation of the company is impossible, rescue measures may yield better economic results for most, if not all, stakeholders in the company enterprise. "Corporate rescue" therefore is a favoured alternative to liquidation in most of the developed economies. </para>
    <para>This chapter provides an overview of the ways in which corporate rescue has been effected in Hong Kong, although the focus of the examination is on the mechanisms under the Companies Ordinance (Cap 32) which have been used to effect corporate rescues. The remainder of this Chapter is organised into five parts. Part II and III consider the meaning and significance of corporate rescue. Part IV outlines the methods of corporate rescue. Part V and VI examine various informal approaches and formal legal devices that have been adopted or employed to effect corporate rescue in Hong Kong. </para>
</section>
```

and when i use the below xslt it is showing the output correctly, but i want the space in first para after phrase tag to be removed.

```
<xsl:template name="para" match="section/para">
            <div class="para">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>              
            </div>
</xsl:template>
```

current output is as below.

```
<div class="para"> When a company in financial difficulty is unable to discharge its debts when they are due, a creditor has the right to take actions to, for....</para>
```

and expected output is

```
<div class="para">When a company in financial difficulty is unable to discharge its debts when they are due, a creditor has the right to take actions to, for...</para>
```

i tried using the belowm but it didn't work.

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please try adding this template to your existing XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="para/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
</xsl:template>
```